Need help understanding lagrangian applied to mass on spring problem
I am interested in learning physics, and I was trying to learn about the Lagrangian method for classical mechanics through https://scholar.harvard.edu/files/david-morin/files/cmchap6.pdf, but I already can't understand equations 6.2, 6.3, and 6.4.


Specifically, I do not understand how they used 6.2 and 6.3 to arrive at 6.4. This is what I have attempted:

As you can see, the left hand side works out as expected, but my right hand side has a ma term that isn't correct as per equation 6.4 . As you can probably tell, I am inexperienced in both physics and mathematics, so I have probably made some errors. Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong? Are we supposed to not consider that x and v can be functions of each other (giving rise to the weird chain rule stuff)?

Your speculation in your last statement is correct. The partial derivative in that equation treats $x$ and $\dot x$ as independent variables.

Thank you for clarifying this for me, but why is it that x and ˙ are treated as independent variables? I do not understand the reason for this mathematically.

I think you need to properly learn partial derivatives and the calculus of variations. This particular concept is very subtle and difficult to get across. It is highly non-trivial, so if you are currently confused, that is very normal. On the other hand, there are many good treatments on this beautiful and immensely useful subject, so you should consult them instead.

@naturallyInconsistent This question is a natural conceptual question about a conceptual point often not stressed enough in the presentation of the subject. As the OP has explicitly written, it has nothing to do with partial derivatives and calculus of variations.

@GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 yes, I agree with you that it is a natural conceptual question about a conceptual point that is often not stressed enough in the standard presentation of the subject. However, it is not something we should be expected to remedy, when in fact rather exemplary videos and textbook and lecture presentations of the subject out there. Just because most teachers are not stellar does not mean that great presentations are hard to come by.

@naturallyInconsistent According to your point of view, access to his site should be limited to people with a PhD in Physics. I do not think this is consistent with PSE rules people can read in the Help Centre. This question is on a conceptual issue, the OP  seems satisfied by my answer addressing that issue, and I think that it could be useful to other people with the same problem. I do not see a solid reason for closing it. The possible misunderstanding about the lack of knowledge about partial derivatives and the calculus of variations has been settled by OP.

@GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 This is the typical argument that could be applied to most questions that are closed on this site. This post is focused on checking work. One can usually pull out a conceptual issue from incorrect work, but the heart of this post is "check my work". One has to look at the work to find the error. If the post can be edited to focus on a conceptual issue, then it should be edited to be reopened.

@BioPhysicist You are sticking at the presence of the picture of a handwritten paper. Considering the whole text, you'll realize it was just the consequence of the initial misunderstanding (thinking it was a problem of formal passages instead of a conceptual problem). I completely disagree about considering this post as "check my work." Indeed, I did not read any line in the picture to prepare my answer, which the OP has accepted. I think it would be enough to reconsider the status of this question.

@GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 I am not stuck on the image. If it was formatted correctly I would have the same view. Your answer has done an excellent job at addressing the issue, but I am judging the post, not the content of a good answer. Any "check my work" errors will have some sort of misunderstanding; clearly that is not a sufficient criterion. I take posts as they are, not what good post could be pulled out from it.

Your problem is not formal but conceptual.
It is true that once you get a solution for the dynamics described by a Lagrangian $\dot x$ depends on $x$. However, when introducing a Lagrangian, it enters the theory as a function of two independent variables. For clarity, let's use the symbols $x$ and $v$. One could introduce different Lagrangians with the structure
$$
L(v,x) = K(v) - V(x)
$$
by varying independently how the functions $K$ and $V$ depend on their independent variables. Notice that at the level of $L$, no time dependence of $x$ and $v$ is present. We are interested in $L$ as a function of two independent variables.
Some additional requirements are introduced when using $L$ as a generator for the dynamics.

$x$ and $v$ are considered functions of a one-dimensional parameter (the time);
a functional of $x(t)$ and $v(t)$ is introduced (the action $S=\int_{t_1}^{t_2} L(x(t),v(t))dt$);
we constrain the action to be a functional of $x(t)$ only by requiring the additional condition that $v$ is the time derivative of $x$ (i.e., $v(t) = \dot x(t)$).

The key point is that the connection between $v$ and $\dot x$ is introduced as an additional requirement only at obtaining the equations of motion for $x$ starting with a function of two independent variables (the Lagrangian). The assumption in the previous step, $3$, does not change the nature of being a two-variable function of $L$.
Everything else is just mechanical calculation.
